# Update a table using SqlAdapter

Tags: vb.net, telerik, sqldataadapter

I am developing an application where it displays a table that I have on the server and I would like the user to update it (insert/delete/update) directly within the application.

I created a telerik `RadGridView` named `definitionView` to display the data and I am following the instructions given directly from the Telerik Documentation: [Updating the Database with ADO.NET](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/populating-with-data/updating-the-database-with-ado.net?_ga=2.52730412.583110131.1666169094-783575710.1664200466&_gl=1*xh0bm7*_ga*NzgzNTc1NzEwLjE2NjQyMDA0NjY.*_ga_9JSNBCSF54*MTY2NjI2ODE0NC4xMy4xLjE2NjYyNzI2NTAuMC4wLjA.)

However I am stuck with the first part: [Updating the database when the current row is changed](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/populating-with-data/updating-the-database-with-ado.net?_ga=2.52730412.583110131.1666169094-783575710.1664200466&_gl=1*xh0bm7*_ga*NzgzNTc1NzEwLjE2NjQyMDA0NjY.*_ga_9JSNBCSF54*MTY2NjI2ODE0NC4xMy4xLjE2NjYyNzI2NTAuMC4wLjA.#updating-the-database-when-the-current-row-is-changed)

I tried to adapt the code shown in the example to my code but I keep getting an error on the `adapter.Update()` statement.

```
Public Class definitionSolution
    Private lastEditRow As DataRow = Nothing
    Private bindingSource

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim bindingSource As New BindingSource
        Dim dsSolution As New DataSet()
        adapter.Fill(dsSolution, "MyTable")
        bindingSource.DataSource = dsSolution.Tables("MyTable")
        definitionView.DataSource = bindingSource
        AddHandler bindingSource.CurrentChanged, AddressOf DefinitionView_CurrentChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub AutoSavingDataBSEventsForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'nwindDataSet.Employees' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Dim dsSolution As New DataSet()
        adapter.Fill(dsSolution, "MyTable")
        bindingSource.DataSource = dsSolution.Tables("MyTable")
        Dim current As Object = bindingSource.Current
        If current IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.lastEditRow = (CType(current, DataRowView)).Row
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DefinitionView_CurrentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim dataRow As DataRow = CType(CType(sender, BindingSource).Current, DataRowView).Row
        If lastEditRow IsNot Nothing AndAlso lastEditRow.RowState = DataRowState.Modified Then
            adapter.Update(lastEditRow)
        End If
        lastEditRow = dataRow
    End Sub
End Class
```

SQLDataAdapter is initialized in another module as follow:

```
Public queryString = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].Mytable"
Public adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, DB_CONNECTION)
```

The error is the following:

```
Error BC30518   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Update' can be called with these arguments:
- Public Overrides Function Update(dataSet As DataSet) As Integer': Value of type 'DataRow' cannot be converted to 'DataSet
- Public Overloads Function Update(dataRows As DataRow()) As Integer': Value of type 'DataRow' cannot be converted to 'DataRow()
- Public Overloads Function Update(dataTable As DataTable) As Integer': Value of type 'DataRow' cannot be converted to 'DataTable
```

Does anybody has an idea on how to solve this issue?

Also from their doc:

> Let's assume that we have an ADO.NET DataTable that loads its data from a SqlDataAdapter and it is bound to a BindingSource component. Further, the BindingSource component is bound to RadGridView control.

I understand that I have a DataSet from SqlDataAdapter that is bound to a BindingSource component but I miss the last bit. What does it mean to bound a BindingSource to the RadGridView control?

---

## Edit after @jmcilhinney comments

Switching from `adapter.Update(lastEditRow)` to `adapter.Update(dsSolution)` gives me the following error:

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: 'Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Update' is most specific for these arguments:
    'Public Overrides Function Update(dataSet As System.Data.DataSet) As Integer':
        Not most specific.
    'Public Function Update(dataRows As System.Data.DataRow()) As Integer':
        Not most specific.
    'Public Function Update(dataTable As System.Data.DataTable) As Integer':
        Not most specific.'
```

Switching from `adapter.Update(lastEditRow)` to `adapter.Update(lastEditRow.ItemArray)` gives me the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Data.DataRow[]'
```

Comment: If you're going to save changes row by row like that, without passing the `DataTable` itself to `Update`, then you should be calling `AcceptChanges` to keep the local data in sync with the database.

Comment: @jmcilhinney do you mean that changing `adapter.Update(lastEditRow)` to `adapter.Update(dsSolution.Tables("MyTable"))` should be enough?

Comment: @legends1337, that would do it. Of course, why do you even have a `DataSet` in the first place? Whay aren't you just creating a `DataTable` and populating that?

Comment: Also, get rid of that constructor. It's pointless. Add the `BindingSource` in the designer, declare a `DataTable` field and create the `DataTable` object there, then do all the retrieving and binding in the `Load` event handler.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry but this is my first days using vb.net... I tried to change from `adapter.Update(lastEditRow)` to `adapter.Update(lastEditRow.ItemArray)` in order to convert the single row to an array but now I get the following error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Data.DataRow[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data adapter's `Update` method accepts multiple rows and performs inserts, updates and deletes as required. That `Update` method is overloaded and it will accept a `DataRow` array, so you can put your single row into an array and pass that:

```vb
adapter.Update({lastEditRow})
```

Otherwise, you need to pass the whole `DataTable` and let it pick out the row(s) that needs saving.

Comment: Thank you! I do have another error `Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows` but I guess this is a completely different issue.